# Word for someone who is constantly yet excessively stressed

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a noun for someone who unduly stresses? For example, a worrywart is someone who constantly yet excessively worries. However, there is [a vast difference between "stressing" and "worrying,"](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/26/smarter-living/the-difference-between-worry-stress-and-anxiety.html) so "bundle of nerves" does not count. Therefore, a _______ is someone who constantly yet excessively stresses.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Anxiety is marked by excessive stress, so *anxious*, perhaps.

Comment: @user405662 Yes, but anxious is not a noun (i.e., someone cannot be an "anxious"). I appreciate your help, though.

Comment: I doubt there is a noun you can use there.

Comment: Most adjectives can be nouned, to refer to someone or something that is characterized by the adjective.

Comment: I can't think of a word for this, either. But there are some animals that are typically viewed as anxious, you might be able to use one of these figuratively.

Comment: @Lambie I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: @Barmar I think you are getting somewhere. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, none actually come to mind.

Comment: @Barmar That's all right! Thank you for your help anyhow. :)

Answer (score 1):

While "burnout" is a noun synonymous with fatigue and apathy born out from stress, it does not suggest a person with said traits. I would use a *neurotic* to fit the bill.

Source: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/neurotic